# How to transform only 2 properties but keep remaining same as is in a nested object structure?

Tags: javascript, json, object

Apologies if title is not clear.
I am using **json2csv** npm package to prepare csv from json object and this package allows us to add a hook to transform object before actual csv line is prepared.

I only need to manipulate two properties out of all. How can I do this effectively? My code feels too bloated.

```
const {
  Parser: Json2csvParser,
  transforms: { unwind },
} = require('json2csv');

const json2csvFields = [
  { value: 'root.filename', label: 'File Name' },
  { value: 'issue.root.priority', label: 'Priority' },
  { value: 'issue.root.url', label: 'URL' },
  { value: 'issue.root.startline', label: 'Start Line' },
  { value: 'issue.root.stopline', label: 'Stop Line' },
  { value: 'issue.root.startcolumn', label: 'Start Column' },
  { value: 'issue.root.stopcolumn', label: 'Stop Column' },
  { value: 'issue.root.issuename', label: 'Issue Name' },
  { value: 'issue.root.issuecategory', label: 'Issue Category' },
  { value: 'issue._', label: 'Issue Description' },
];

const sampleData = [
  {
    root: {
      filename:
        '/home/users/john-doe/workspace/foo-project/src/main/classes/foo.cls',
    },
    issue: {
      root: {
        priority: 1,
        url: 'www.example.com',
        startline: 100,
        stopline: 105,
        startcolumn: 20,
        stopcolumn: 25,
        issuename: 'blah',
        issuecategory: 'Category A',
      },
      _: '     Fox     ',
    },
  },
];

const json2csvOptions = {
  fields: json2csvFields,
  quote: '',
  header: true,
  transforms: [
    (item) => ({
      'root.filename': item.root.filename.replace(
        '/home/users/john-doe/workspace/foo-project/src/main/classes/',
        ''
      ),
      'issue._': `"${item.issue._.trim()}"`,
      // Except for the above two, everything else doens't need any transformation.
      'issue.root.priority': item.issue.root.priority,
      'issue.root.url': item.issue.root.url,
      'issue.root.startline': item.issue.root.startline,
      'issue.root.stopline': item.issue.root.stopline,
      'issue.root.startcolumn': item.issue.root.startcolumn,
      'issue.root.stopcolumn': item.issue.root.stopcolumn,
      'issue.root.issuename': item.issue.root.issuename,
      'issue.root.issuecategory': item.issue.root.issuecategory,
    }),
  ],
};

const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser(json2csvOptions);

const csv = json2csvParser.parse(sampleData);
console.log(csv);
```

This prints below output:

```
File Name,Priority,URL,Start Line,Stop Line,Start Column,Stop Column,Issue Name,Issue Category,Issue Description
foo.cls,1,www.example.com,100,105,20,25,blah,Category A,"Fox"
```

**EDIT**: Updated code to a working example.

Comment: Does the desired property name literally have `.`s in it? Because, eg, `'issue.root.priority':` is pretty different from `item.issue.root.priority` - you are doing some transformation there

Comment: @CertainPerformance That is right. property names have `.` in it. To access 
property `issue.root.startline`, I have to do `item.issue.root.startline`.

Comment: Here is a screenshot from library page: https://imgur.com/DjDhKwC
I will try to add a complete example that can be executed.

Comment: Does the original `issue.root` object have any other properties not extracted in the code, or have you picked out a subset of them? If there aren't any other properties, it'll be a lot easier

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am pulling everything from `issue.root` not discarding anything. I also updated code sample to a working one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After listing the two properties with special treatment, use `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` to transform all the `issue.root` properties to their flat structure with `.`s in the property names. Then that object can be spread into the returned object.

```
const transformsFn = ({ root, issue }) => ({
  'root.filename': root.filename.replace(
    '/home/users/john-doe/workspace/foo-project/src/main/classes/',
    ''
  ),
  'issue._': `"${issue._.trim()}"`,
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(issue.root).map(
      ([key, val]) => [`issue.root.${key}`, val]
    )
  ),
});
const json2csvOptions = {
  fields: json2csvFields,
  quote: '',
  header: true,
  transforms: [transformsFn],
};
```

Comment: After you pointed out that I am not transforming `item.issue.root` object, I tried to use `...item.issue.root`(spread operator) but it is not working..Why is that?

Comment: You *are* trying to transform it - from a nested object of `{ priority: 1, startline: 100 }` etc to `{ 'issue.root.priority': 1, 'issue.root.startline': 100'` etc. Spreading without transforming will result in an object that's the same as the original one, but you want a different sort of object (with the extra two fields as well).

Comment: I tried your code with a `console.log` and it is actually preparing an object with properties with dot in it, instead of a nested object. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/84FQahm
All the properties from `item.issue.root` are ignored and coming as blank.

Comment: That's the same structure as the object you're creating in your original code - your original code is `(item) => ({ 'issue.root.priority': item.issue.root.priority,` etc - which produces a flat object with no nesting, but with properties which contain `.`s, just like the `Object.fromEntries` / `.entries` approach in my answer is doing. If you actually wanted a nested object, that's not what your original code is doing.

Comment: Awesome. When I implemented your solution, I added extra prefix before property names thinking you forgot to add that. But your solution was spot on and didn't need any further change. Thanks for looking into it. 